GraphQL Federation for conditional dependencies
Suppose I have 3 datapoints in 3 separate subgraphs
Data Point A in "Subgraph 1"
Data Point B in "Subgraph 2"
Data Point C in "Subgraph 3"

A depends on B and C conditionally. There is another data point D in "Subgraph 1".  Based on the value of datapoint D, Subgraph 1 needs to either fetch data from Subgraph 2 or Subgraph 3.
How would I do this by making minimal subgraph calls.
As of now, I have to make calls to Both Subgraph 2 and Subgraph 3 and pass the value D to them for taking the decision.
// Subgraph 1
type EntityHere @key (fields: "D"){
    D: boolean
    A: string @requires(fields: "B C") // both are required hence both subgraphs are called
    B: string @external
    C: string @external 
}

// Subgraph 2
type EntityHere @key (fields: "D") {
    D: boolean
    B: string 
}

// Subgraph 3
type EntityHere @key (fields: "D"){
    D: boolean
    C: string
}

As you can see in the above example, because A requires B and C both since there is no way to conditionally call them, both subgraphs are called, and the value of D is passed to them.
I have left out the implementation of resolvers to keep it simple. I can add it if needed.
Subgraph 1
EntityHere : {
    A: (reference, args, request) => {
        if(reference.D === "B"){
             return reference.B
        } else if (reference.D === "C"){
             return reference.C
        }
    },
}

Subgraph 2
EntityHere : {
    B: (reference, args, request) => {
        if(reference.D === "B"){
             var b = fetchB() // network call to service of B
             return b
        }
    },
}

Subgraph 3
EntityHere : {
    C: (reference, args, request) => {
        if(reference.D === "C"){
             var c = fetchC() // network call to service of C
             return c
        }
    },
}

I need a way to call the Subgraph 2 or Subgraph 3 conditionally so that I don't have to unnecessarily scale up infra of one when another is supposed to receive major percentage of traffic.

It will be helpful to provide your resolvers, as you would need to remove the @requires directive from A since it currently forces both subgraphs to be called. Then use custom logic in the resolver for A to call the appropriate subgraph based on the value of D. Unless there is a teason not to.

I have added the resolvers for the example mentioned. Since the datapoint B and C sit in other subgraphs and I don't want to make calls to their microservices from Subgraph 1 I am not sure how this will work since you cant call the subgraphs from a subgraph, since those calls are done by router based on schema given.

One of the option we are thinking of is making direct subgraph to subgraph calls. Some implications I can think of

We will have to ditch the requires directive in the chain of dependencies getting created as it wont be compatible with subgraph to subgraph calls
GQL is an aggregation layer and ideally should not be containing any logic. Most of the dependencies are pure data so you might as well call the service directly

What are your thoughts on this.

Would be great if someone can put some light on the subgraph to subgraph calls caveats as an answer. I can award this bounty to them. Would be sad to see the bounty to go to a waste.
